# MVC Routes/RouteDebugger work when deployed to IIS7 but not in Cassini

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am currently working on an MVC3 Application, and after fighting with some routes, noticed some odd behaviors:

- I have added new routes, but these are not reflecting when I run the application with F5 in Cassini via Visual Studio 2010.  If I deploy this same code to a server (with the same web.config) running IIS7, my new routes work.
- I have installed Phil Haack's RouteDebugger tool.  The web.config is set to have this enabled, but it does not display when running my site via Visual Studio 2010/Cassini.  It works properly when deployed to a remote server with IIS7 - again, same config file.

Any thoughts?  Is there some config/setup option that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If there's no requirement to use the Dev Web Server, have you tried IIs Express instead? It's a better dev web server that is much closer to the "real" IIs.

Comment: Switched to IIS Express - same result.  So odds are there's something that is messing with local execution and not reflecting my changes...

Comment: deploy to a clean machine running VS10 - you're not running the same bits (config or otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

Looked to be a weird caching issue.  After fighting with this for a day, by chance I opened up a different branch (main) of the same application, which worked fine.

Performed a reverse/forward integration and the main branch worked fine, dev branch still would not show the changes.

Did a comparison, and they were exactly the same bits.

Did a 'Get Specific Version' from TFS, overwriting everything, and the problem persisted.

Finally, I deleted both branches from my local drive, and then did a Get Specific Version, and suddenly everything worked.  Odds are this solved the issue because it forced all of the bin/obj files to be wiped out (although in theory they should have been rebuilt since I was doing a Rebuild Solution).

All in all a really weird issue, so I figured I'd post this just in case someone runs into the same issue down the line, given the difficulty of debugging this.

Comment: I've experienced this weird behaviour and I assumed it was Cassini, but now that you've mentioned your switch to IIS Express with the same result, it makes me wonder what the real issue is.  I'm not using any source control for my own projects (which is where I've experienced this), so other than VS2010, I don't know what the common factor is here.  There really isn't much information available either.  Thanks for posting this though.  It might help someone narrow it down further at some point.

Comment: @John - Maybe if it pops up again, try deleting out all of the OBJ/BIN folders and see if that forces the reboot?

Comment: If it comes up again then I'll give that a shot and leave a comment here.  Thanks for the suggestion!